# Ramification in Galois Closure

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following: Let $\Omega$ be the Galois Closure of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $O_\Omega$. What are the possible values of $e(P|P\cap \mathbb{Z})$ and $f(P|P\cap \mathbb{Z})$ ($e$ and $f$ being the ramification index and inertial degree)?
$$ $$
I manged to figure out the possible values for ideals in $O_{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]}$ using the discriminant, but what can I say about the Galois Closure?

Answer (score 1):

Keith Conrad's notes [The splitting field of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/Qw2.pdf) explain everything about this, see Theorem $5$. Your $\Omega$ is denoted by $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$ there.